# Хороший модуль ACL для Kohana 3 с описанием как его включить в проект

Tags: framework, php, kohana, база-данных

Подскажите, пожалуйста, хороший модуль `ACL` для `Kohana` 3 с описанием как его включить в проект?

На русском нет не единой документации под данные модули.

На `GitHub` довольно неплохое разнообразие модулей под Кохану, но не один не могу понять как сделать. Не хватает навыков перевода. Плюс к этому никогда не имел дела с Zend'овской системой ACL, а как я понял, основные моменты позаимствованы оттуда.

`Kohana 3.3.1 ACL`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если гора не идет к Магомету... 
[Описание Zend ACL](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/ru/zend.acl.introduction.html)
А на гите скачайте адаптацию данного модуля под `Kohana`

Comment: Прочитал мануал. В принципе то механизм понятен. Правила наследуются, создаются через методы класса. А где хранятся? Куда создаются? Как это все в БД оформлено? Таблица не таблица? В конфиг файл в живую рисует?

Библиотека скачана A1 A2 ACL а вот как это все завести ? рычага не найду никак. В исходники залажу не могу ничего толкового разглядеть как это запустить.

Comment: этих библиотек море, нужна ссылка на ту версию, которую вы планируете использовать, сам по себе Zend ACL насколько я помню абстрактен и нигде ничего не хранит, загрузка и сохранение конфигов производятся уже отдельно

Comment: Да, уже успел по-тестировать! Довольно интересная вещь. Странно что я не касался ее ранее. Читаю в данный момент статейку про реализацию динамичных ACL прав с хранением в БД. http://zendframework.ru/articles/zend_acl-dynamic-acl-part-3

Думаю, должен одуплить что к чему.

Будет инересен механизм реализации ACL в администраторской части. Судя по его документации у него большой спектр взаимодействия между собой, т.е. я могу открывать доступы для пользователя лично к какой либо странице, а могу закрывать доступ целой группе к какому либо разделу сайта.

Answer (score 0):

Есть уже адаптированный для Kohana модуль ACL: deputy. Адаптированный из того самого Zend ACL

Comment: я так понял, их документации, что этот вид ACL он основан на URL запросе, и все же не сохраняет сами права доступа где-то в базе.

Comment: да, основан на URI, права можно (и нужно) хранить в БД, но в сам класс нужно отдавать массив для проверки права пользователя посмотреть страницу